# ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wsimport

I have a wsdl from ERP cloud. To consume it in Java, I compiled it using `wsimport` and extracted all the java files.

Now I'm trying to use these java files in order to communicate to the server data through wsdl. The wsdl requires authentication.

**Problem**

Whenever I try to run my custom code to connect to wsdl, for authentication it works with simple setting of username and password in Binding context.

```
private void attachAuthentication(Object className) {
    BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) className;
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "xxx");
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "xxx");
}
```

But whenever I deploy my code on a weblogic GPI instance, it gives me following error.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: The request was invalid or malformed Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP12Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP12Fault.java:229)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
```

[image]
I tried attaching a Soap handler to my SEI. Here's what I've done.

**InitializeErp.java**

```
HeaderHandlerResolver handlerResolver = new HeaderHandlerResolver();

InvoiceInterfaceService_Service interfaceInvoice = new InvoiceInterfaceService_Service();
interfaceInvoice.setHandlerResolver(handlerResolver);
invoiceInterfaceServiceSoapHttpPort = interfaceInvoice.getInvoiceInterfaceServiceSoapHttpPort();
```

**HeaderHandlerResolver.java**

```
public class HeaderHandlerResolver implements HandlerResolver {

    @Override
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
        List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();

        HandlerHeader hh = new HandlerHeader();

        handlerChain.add(hh);

        return handlerChain;
    }
}
```

**HeaderHandler.java**

```
public class HandlerHeader implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {


    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        final Boolean outInd = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outInd) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z'");

            Date creationDate = new Date();
            Date expirationDate = new Date(creationDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1));
            try {

                SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
                SOAPEnvelope env = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                env.addNamespaceDeclaration("sch", "http://xmlns.oracle.com/scheduler");
                env.addNamespaceDeclaration("typ", "http://xmlns.oracle.com/scheduler/types");

                SOAPHeader header = env.getHeader();
                SOAPBody body = env.getBody();

                env.removeNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV");

                env.setPrefix("soapenv");
                header.setPrefix("soapenv");
                body.setPrefix("soapenv");

                QName security = new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security", "wsse");
                // Constructing Header
                SOAPElement securityElement = header.addChildElement(security);
                securityElement.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
                securityElement.setAttribute("soapenv:mustUnderstand", "1");

                QName usernameToken = new QName("UsernameToken", "wsse");
                SOAPElement usernameTokenElement = securityElement.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
                usernameTokenElement.setAttribute("wsu:Id", "UsernameToken-97B1FF404874F4997215144527824364");

                QName username = new QName("Username", "wsse");
                SOAPElement usernameElement = usernameTokenElement.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
                usernameElement.addTextNode("xxx");

                QName passwrod = new QName("Password", "wsse");
                SOAPElement passwordElement = usernameTokenElement.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");
                passwordElement.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
                passwordElement.addTextNode("xxx");

                QName nonce = new QName("Nonce", "wsse");
                SOAPElement nonceElement = usernameTokenElement.addChildElement("Nonce", "wsse");
                nonceElement.setAttribute("EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
                nonceElement.addTextNode("Ox0BI3sh1pPSe2S7NsUzeg==");

                QName created = new QName("Created", "wsu");
                SOAPElement createdElement = usernameTokenElement.addChildElement("Created", "wsu");
                createdElement.addTextNode(format.format(creationDate));

                QName timestamp = new QName("Timestamp", "wsu");
                SOAPElement timestampElement = securityElement.addChildElement("Timestamp", "wsu");
                timestampElement.setAttribute("wsu:Id", "TS-4");

                QName createdTimestamp = new QName("Created", "wsu");
                SOAPElement createdTimestampElement = timestampElement.addChildElement("Created", "wsu");
                createdTimestampElement.addTextNode(format.format(creationDate));

                QName expiresTimestamp = new QName("Expires", "wsu");
                SOAPElement expiresTimestampElement = timestampElement.addChildElement("Expires", "wsu");
                expiresTimestampElement.addTextNode(format.format(expirationDate));
                // Print out the outbound SOAP message to System.out
                System.out.println("setting attributes...");
                message.writeTo(System.out);

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("message printed..");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {

        try {
            SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(out);
            String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
            RequestFilter.getSession().setAttribute("soap fault", "Soap ->" + strMsg);
        } catch (SOAPException | IOException ex) {
            RequestFilter.getSession().setAttribute("mailContent", ex.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    }
}
```

This is what my Soap HEader looks like.

[image]

On running it on server. This is what I get in my SoapFault

```
Soap  -> ns1:Senderns2:InvalidRequestThe request was invalid or malformedweblogic.wsee.security.wst.faults.InvalidRequestException: Server Authentication Required at weblogic.wsee.security.wst.framework.TrustSoapClient.invoke(TrustSoapClient.java:157) at weblogic.wsee.security.wst.framework.TrustSoapClient.requestTrustToken(TrustSoapClient.java:110) at weblogic.wsee.security.saml.SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.createCredential(SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.java:432) at
```

[image]

I've many ways to modify the Soap header, Removed security, just passed username password, Added both handler as well as credentials in BindingContext, But nothing seems to work on server.

With the header attached, I get the following error on local[image]

I'm out of ways now. Can anyone please suggest me any approach or point out what am I missing. What should I try now. Any help is appreciated. All suggestions are welcome.